# Delete and redirect to the page in php

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to delete the entry in php and redirect the page in php.
I need to redirect the page based on condition as `header("Location: report2.php?region=$region");` after deletion page doesnt get redirected to `header("Location: report2.php?region=$region");` 
It doesnt delete also. It only redirects to report2.php?delete_id=103
Here is the code

```
  ?php
//Give your mysql username password and database name
include_once "db.php";
if(isset($_REQUEST['region']))
{
$region=$_REQUEST['region'];

//connection to the database


$qresult = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM registration where region='".$region."'");

    echo "<h1>Registration Details of $region Region.</h1>";
if (mysql_num_rows($qresult) == 0) { 
echo "<h3 style=color:#0000cc;text-align:center;>No Registrations Done..!</h3>"; 
} else { 


        echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' class='reports'>";

        echo "<tr>" .
                    "<td style='background: #f1f1f1; font-weight: bold;text-align:center;'>Registration Number</td>" .
                    "<td style='background: #f1f1f1; font-weight: bold;text-align:center;'>Name</td>" . 
"</tr>";

        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($qresult)) { 
                       echo "<tr>" .
                    "<td style=text-align:center;>" . $row['id'] . "</td>" . 

                    "<td style=text-align:center;>".  $row['name']  . "</td>"; 


                ?>

              <td><a href="javascript:delete_id(<?php echo $row['id']; ?>)"><img src="images/delete21.png" alt="Delete" /></a></td>


                    </tr>
        <?php   
        }
        }}
        ?>
        </table>
 <?php
 if(isset($_GET['delete_id']))
  {
    $sql_query="DELETE FROM registration WHERE id=".$_GET['delete_id'];
    mysql_query($sql_query);

    header("Location: report2.php?region=$region");
    exit;
  }

?>
```

Comment: Where do you set 'region'? I think thats why it doesn't work, because region is never set, therefore it never executes the code in your if-statement.

Comment: You must not output anything before using the `header` function, which is not the case here.

Comment: Everything you set is the delete_id

Comment: 1. Don't use the deprecated `mysql_*`-functions. They are deprecated since PHP 5.5 and completely removed in PHP 7. Use MySQLi or PDO instead. 2. You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries, which can be used if you use the above mentioned MySQLi or PDO.

Comment: actuually there is adminlogin when user login using username,password and region. after login it redirects to header("Location: report2.php?region=$region");. This is working fine. While using delete option I am not able to redirect it to the same page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is based on bad formatting, therefore you didn't notice that your if doesn't close before the next if-statement, which I don't think you intended.

Here is your fixed and formatted code:

```
<?php

  include_once "db.php";
  if(isset($_REQUEST['region'])) 
  {
    $region=$_REQUEST['region'];

    $sql_query="SELECT * FROM registration where region='".$region."' ";
    $result_set=mysql_query($sql_query);
  }
  if(isset($_GET['delete_id']))
  {

    $sql_query="SELECT * FROM registration where id='".$_GET['delete_id']."' ";
    $result=mysql_query($sql_query);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
      $region = $row['region'];
    }

    $sql_query="DELETE FROM registration WHERE id=".$_GET['delete_id'];
    mysql_query($sql_query);

    header("Location: report2.php?region=".$region);
    exit;
  }

?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function delete_id(id) {
      if(confirm('Sure To Remove This Record ?')) {
          window.location.href='report2.php?delete_id='+id;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: alright, changing it back, thought it was a typing error, my bad :)

Comment: @user6582683 - You need to move the PHP block to the top of the file, before the JS or any other output, or the `header("Location: ...")` won't work. Like one of the comments says, **you can't output anything before you send headers**

Comment: You should throw in an `exit;` after the header as well, to make sure the script won't continue executing.

Comment: thanks, changed it. make sure the rest of your html/js code is below that aswell

Comment: I changed the code after deleting it redirects to http://localhost/abc/report2.php?region=. Region name is not displayed.

Comment: thats because we dont have $region set in that case, which region do we want to go after deleting?

Comment: Where do I need to set region now for delete?

Comment: I did it for you, should work and $region should be the region from the id we deleted.

Comment: I used the above code still it redirects to localhost/abc/report2.php?region=

Comment: I dont get any error messages delete works fine only during redirect it goes to localhost/abc/report2.php?region=.

Comment: i changed the header line and sql statement, try it again :)